# Failing to verify signature

Tags: solidity, signature, verify, ecrecover, ecdsa

I'm trying to verify a signature using OpenZeppelin's `SignatureChecker` library, but always returns false. This is the verify function from the lib:

```js
    function isValidSignatureNow(
        address signer,
        bytes32 hash,
        bytes memory signature
    ) internal view returns (bool) {
        (address recovered, ECDSA.RecoverError error) = ECDSA.tryRecover(hash, signature);
        if (error == ECDSA.RecoverError.NoError && recovered == signer) {
            return true;
        }

        (bool success, bytes memory result) = signer.staticcall(
            abi.encodeWithSelector(IERC1271.isValidSignature.selector, hash, signature)
        );
        return (success && result.length == 32 && abi.decode(result, (bytes4)) == IERC1271.isValidSignature.selector);
    }
```

And this is how I'm generating the signature using Ethers.js:
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer--signing-methods

```js
const dataToSign = {"data1":"value1","data2":"value2"};

const dataHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(
   ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(JSON.stringify(dataToSign))
);
const dataHashBin = ethers.utils.arrayify(dataHash);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PK);
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(dataHashBin);

const isValid = await signTest.verify(wallet.address, dataHash, signature); //--> inherits OP's lib
//have passed 'dataHashBin' instead of 'dataHash', same issue

console.log(isValid); // ---> false every time
```

I think the problem is in how I'm generating the signature, but can't figure out why I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

```js
const dataToSign = {"data1":"value1","data2":"value2"};

const dataHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(
   ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(dataToSign)
);
const dataHashBin = ethers.utils.arrayify(dataHash);

const ethHash = ethers.utils.hashMessage(dataHashBin);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PK);
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(dataHashBin);

const isValid = await signTest.verify(wallet.address, ethHash, signature);

console.log(isValid); //true
```